# Lodash _.debounce is not canceling existing timer when function is called again in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, lodash

I'm trying to debounce the onChange event for a form in my React component.  I plan on moving `debounceStateUpdate` into a static utils function to universalize the debounce time, which is why that extra layer exists rather than just directly using `_.debounce`.

```
const ProfileGeneralEditContent = props => {
    const debounceStateUpdate = updateFunction => {
        return _.debounce(params => updateFunction(params), 700);
    };

    const FormsyFieldUpdated = debounceStateUpdate((config) => {
        console.log("update some things here");
    });

    return (
        <Formsy
            onChange={(config) => {
                FormsyFieldUpdated.cancel();
                FormsyFieldUpdated(config);
            }}
            onInvalid={() => setValid(false)}
            onValid={() => setValid(true)}
        >
            <div className={'flex justify-start items-start'}>
            .
            .
            . (more jsx)
```

I would think that when the `onChange` event fires, the `cancel()` call would cancel any existing debounce timers that are running and start a new one.

My goal is to debounce inputs from updating state on each key press, so that state will only update after 700ms of no updates.  But currently, this code is only delaying each key press' state update by 700 milliseconds, and the state updates for each key press is still happening.

How do I use `_.debounce` to keep a single running debounce timer for delaying my state update, rather than having 10 timers running at once for each key that is pressed?

Answer (score 4):

I figured it out.  I needed to wrap my debounced function definition in `useCallback()`, because the re-rendering of the component was redefining the debounced function every keypress and thus it would have no knowledge of its previous iterations' running functions.

```
const ProfileGeneralEditContent = props => {
    const debounceStateUpdate = updateFunction => {
        return _.debounce(params => updateFunction(params), 700);
    };

    const FormsyFieldUpdated = useCallback(debounceStateUpdate((config) => {
        console.log("update some things here");
    }), []);

    return (
        <Formsy
            onChange={(config) => FormsyFieldUpdated(config)}
            onInvalid={() => setValid(false)}
            onValid={() => setValid(true)}
        >
            <div className={'flex justify-start items-start'}>
            .
            .
            . (more jsx)
```